# scss ParseError when running "npm run build" for react website?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am not a react developer, I do swift programing, so I am not familiar using react and am getting the below error when trying to build the app so I can deploy it.

When I look at *line 1* the error is referring to, it is the code " *$theme-colors: (* " so I am not sure why this line is creating an error or if it is actually referring to somewhere else in the file??

I have posted some of the code here in the file but not all of it because the file is 300+ lines long so hopefully this can be debugged from what is here.

This react-app used to build perfectly fine and it seems without doing anything it stopped working...?

Anyone know what the problem could be?

After running "npm run build" I get:

> ```
> Creating an optimized production build...  
> Failed to compile.  
>   
> ./src/index.scss  
> ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 25
> ```

**src/index.scss** starting with line 1

```scss
$theme-colors: (        <- Line 1
  "primary": #00e1ff,
  "secondary": #353535,
  "black": #000,
  "ass": #858585,
);

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px,
  xxxl: 1600px,
);


$font-family-sans-serif: "Montserrat", sans-serif;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
@import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";

.mat-select-black {
  .MuiSelect-select:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .MuiSelect-icon {
    color: #000000 !important;
  }
}
.mat-select-dark2 {
  .MuiSelect-select:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .MuiSelect-icon {
    color: #9vvxb3 !important;
  }
}
<MORE_CODE_AVAILABLE_IF_NEEDED>
```

Comment: I tried that and got the error: "SassError: Expected expression. $theme-colors: {
  src/index.scss 1:16  root stylesheet", so I am guessing they are not the problem..

Answer (score 0):

i think its your problemm
you need to define map from names to values that you can then access using variables.
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#advanced-variable-functions

Comment: This react-app has always worked when running "npm run build" before so why would it all of the sudden need new syntax?

Comment: its dont need a new syntax its need to define new map before use.Read the info after link please

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe because you are using sass map module without importing it first. Try adding this at the top:

```
@use "sass:map";
```

See [sass maps docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps).

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same error, literally no difference in error message.

Comment: strange. can we see the part of your webpack config that processes the sass? btw this questions has little to do with react, and is strictly sass related. you could use sass in a non-react project.